# Powerpoint attaching a VBA function on a button

Tags: vba, button, powerpoint

I have found how to create a button and I want to make it so when I press it it does the following function.

<-Button->

```
Sub AddButton()
   Dim cb As CommandBar

   Set cb = Application.CommandBars.Add("additional_toolbar", msoBarTop, , True)

   With cb.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
      .Caption = "click me"
      .OnAction = "macro_name"
      .Style = msoButtonCaption
   End With
   cb.Visible = True
End Sub
```

<-Action that I want it to perform->

```
Sub CopySizeAndPosition()

    ' Usage: Select two shapes. The size and position of
    ' the first shape selected will be copied to the second.

    Dim w As Double
    Dim h As Double
    Dim l As Double
    Dim t As Double

    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
        w = .Width
        h = .Height
    End With
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2)
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
    End With

End Sub
```

Do u know how I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

.OnAction = "macro_name"

To:

.OnAction = "CopySizeAndPosition"

Comment: I did that and it seems the correct thing to do. But when I run it, I get a run time error '5'. Do I need to keep the Modules separately or in the same file??Thank you for you answer, anyway.Sorry I am not a programmer yet!I don't know why this button sometimes is created and sometimes it gives you a runtime error..

Comment: When I try to debug it, it stops in this line:
Set cb = Application.CommandBars.Add("additional_toolbar", msoBarTop, , True

Do you know what is wrong with it?

Comment: If the command bar is there already when you try to add it, you'll get an error.  You'll need to trap the error in case it occurs.